# Org-mode babel python session does not produce results

Tags: python, org-mode, python-babel

I'm trying to write up a code test case using org-mode and babel but can't get past the first step:

```
* Running code example

Set up some variables
#+begin_src python :results output :session
x=1
#+end_src


Use some variables (in the end I'll have more useful
explanatory text between the code blocks).
#+begin_src python :exports both :results output :session 
print "Hi", x
#+end_src
```

Hitting `C-c` on the blocks in sequence fails since the second block
doesn't have `x` defined.

Exporting the file (to PDF if that matters) seems to execute all of the 
code blocks, but the `RESULTS` of the second block are not constructed
and inserted into the buffer.

How can I modify the switches on the code-blocks so that everything
is executed in a session, and the results are embedded in the 
org buffer?

`org-version=7.9.3f`

Comment: I don't have Python, so I cannot try. But I don't see some obvious reason why it wouldn't work, as long as it's run in a session. Don't you have to add a name after the session parameter, maybe?

Comment: Tried with a session name added -- same problem.

Comment: For me, with org-mode v8.2.10 it works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Give the session a name, for example:

```
    #+name: session_init
    #+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :session example
    str='Hello, World'
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS: session_init
    : 
    : str='Hello World'
    : >>> >>> >>>
    : 

    #+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :session example
    print str
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS:
    : print str
    : Hello, World
    :
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with a newer org-mode (e.g. 8.2.10); there are major changes from org 8.0 so the best way is to upgrade your org-mode.